# Which dependence do two arrays have if second array was created from the first array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, assign

I'm creating two arrays, the first has the entries, and the second is empty.
I am assigning one cell, the first `array[0]` to the second array. And I am applying method `pop()` for second array. Why cell, the first array too change its value?

```js
var t = [[1,1,1], [1,1,1,1,1], [1,1,1,1]];
var t1 = t[0];
t1.pop();
console.log(t[0]);
```

I am getting:

```
[
  1,
  1
]
```

Why it's happening?

Comment: When you're creating t1, you're just assigning a reference to the array inside of t, you're not copying it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## `pop()`

> The pop() method removes the last element from an array and returns that element. This method changes the length of the array.

```js
var t = [[1,1,1], [1,1,1,1,1], [1,1,1,1]];
var t1 = t[0];
t1.pop(); // this is modifying the array in t[0]
console.log(t[0]);
```

To avoid that, you can create a copy before to execute the function `pop()`

```js
var t = [[1,1,1], [1,1,1,1,1], [1,1,1,1]];
var t1 = t[0].slice(); // Creating a copy of array in t[0]
t1.pop();
console.log(t[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to shed light on a different aspect of this problem.

**Arrays** are reference type in JavaScript. That means **pointer** is used to locate an array in memory in javascript. So when you assign

```
var t1 = t[0];
```

you are assigning the `same memory address` pointed by `t[0]` into `t1`.So, `t[0]` and `t1` are basically pointing the same array in `memory`. That's why when popping value from `t1`, It affects the same array pointed by `t[0]` also.That's why `t[0]` value also changes.